# Extracting out the subject and body of an email into a dictionary using Python

Tags: python

I want to extract out the subject and email body from the email archive (a .txt file) in the form of {Subject: Body} format. Following is my txt file

*testing.txt*

```
To: samplemail
From: ssample Sender
Subject: This is the sample request one...
Hey there, 
This is the smaple email just for the test purpose.
No intentions to hurt somebodys feleings at all.
Thanks, 


To: sampleSender2
From: ssampleReciever2
Subject: This is the sample request second...
Hey there, 
this is another sample mail body and just to test the py script working
this si the part of the data preprocesing 
thanks
```

And here is my python file

*test.py*

```
txt = "testing.txt"
file = open(txt)
body = ""
body_list = list()
subject_list = list()
for line in file:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith("From:") or line.startswith("To:"):
        continue
    if line.startswith("Subject:"):
        subject_list.append(line)
    if not line.startswith("Subject:"):
        body = body + line
```

Please help me out with the logic.

Comment: what is the problem/question here? also in the interest of a properly scoped file, you should use `with open(txt) as f: for line in f.readlines(): #dostuff`

Comment: Hmm, those files are **not** normal mail messages. According to RFC5322, an empty line should separate the body part from the header part. Do you really need to parse such a bogus format file? Additionally in common archive files, a `From enveloppe_sender` line (no `:` after From`) marks the beginning of a new message. Again are you sure of your example format?

Comment: Not actually, the original format is a lot different. I wanted to just know the logic for such problems as I am new in Python and never really had deal with such kinda problems before

Answer (score 1):

The expected output format `{Subject: Body}` looks like a dictionary to me, so I would advise you stick with dictionaries as a container. The following will skip any line that starts with "To:", "From:", or "\n". If it encounters a subject line, it generates an entry in a dictionary for that subject line and adds the concatenation of subsequent lines until the next subject line as values to the current subject line.

```
with open("testing.txt") as f:
    data = {}
    for line in f:
        if any(line.startswith(kw) for kw in ("From:", "To:", "\n")):
            continue
        if line.startswith("Subject:"):
            current_subject = line.split(":")[-1].strip()
        else:
            data.setdefault(current_subject, "")
            data[current_subject] += line

print(data)

# {'This is the sample request one...': 'Hey there, \nThis is the smaple email just for the test purpose.\nNo intentions to hurt somebodys feleings at all.\nThanks, \n',
# 'This is the sample request second...': 'Hey there, \nthis is another sample mail body and just to test the py script working\nthis si the part of the data preprocesing \nthanks'}
```

Feel free to `strip` unwanted characters from the lines, as you see fit.

I hope this helps.

Comment: @sajalarora, this program could not end up in an infinite loop as long as the file is finite. Nothing other than contents of the file is being looped through. So, if the file's contents are finite (which I'm sure is the case), then the program should exit. If you're still stuck in an infinite loop, please edit your post and show the code that's causing that because it can't be the code above.

Comment: Hey, sorry actually...there was something wrong with that txt file. It worked just fine with the right file. Thanks anyways...

Answer (score 0):

first version is thisone but you can put it in a dictionary if the subjects are the same like in the second part

## PART 1

```
  subjects =[]
    bodys = []
    with open("test.txt") as file:
        body = ""
        for line in file:
            if line.startswith("From:") or line.startswith("To:"):
                continue
            if line.startswith("Subject:"):
               if body != '':
                   bodys.append(body)
                   body = ""
               subjects.append(line.split("Subject:")[1])
            if not line.startswith("Subject:"):
                body +=line
        bodys.append(body) #appends the last body of the mail
        body = ""
    print(subjects)
    print(bodys)
```

## PART 2

```
    SB ={}
    with open("test.txt") as file:
        body = ""
        subject = ""
        for line in file:
            if line.startswith("From:") or line.startswith("To:"):
                continue
            if line.startswith("Subject:"):
               if body != '':
                   SB[subject] = body
                   body = ""
               subject = line.split("Subject:")[1]
               SB[subject]=''
            if not line.startswith("Subject:"):
                body +=line
        SB[subject] = body
        body = ""

    print(SB)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
email_data, subject, body = {}, "", ""
with open("emails.txt", "r") as records:
    for record in records:
        if record.startswith("Subject:"):
            subject = record.split("Subject:")[1].strip()
        elif not record.startswith("To:") and not record.startswith("From:"):
            body += record
        else:
            subject, body = "", ""
            continue
        email_data[subject] = body
print(email_data)
```